# Do task seconds after video is played

Tags: video, html5-video

I am trying to add an 'onclick' event-listener to my video after 5 seconds that the video has started playing and it should redirect user to a certain URL. My current js code:

```
    document.getElementById('my_video_1').addEventListener("timeupdate", myfunc, false);

    function myfunc() {
        console.log('in my func');
        if (this.currentTime > 5) {
            console.log('in if');
            this.onclick = function () {
                location.href = "www.google.com";
            };
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it seems the function is being executed every time 'timeupdate' fires. But I want to assign the onclick handler to video once the video currenttime reaches 5 and then finish executing myfunc.
Any ideas how I can do this?
Is there any better way to serve my purpose?

Comment: One of two circunstances the `timeupdate` event is fired is when the video is playing ([W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_timeupdate.asp)). If you don't want your function to be executed every time the event fires, I propose first add the `click` event to the video element, and then use the `currentTime` property.

Comment: @CrisMVP3200 Could you give me a sample code pls?

Comment: @MissCode Sure, check below ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, instead of using the `timeupdate` event (which means your function is executed every time your video is playing, or the playback position of it is moved), it's better to use just the `click` event (with the `addEventListener` method, or with the `onclick` property).

```
/* Attach the click event with the addEventListener() method
   By default, the third parameter, useCapture, is false */
document.getElementById("my_video_1").addEventListener("click", myfunc);

/* Attach the click event with the onclick property */ 
document.getElementById("my_video_1").onclick = myfunc;
```

Then, in the function who executes by the click event trigerring, you check if the current time of the video is over 5 seconds.

```
function myfunc() {
    if (this.currentTime > 5) {
        location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    };
}
```

This is the full sample code (contains both HTML and JavaScript):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="my_video_1" width="426px" height="240px" autoplay controls muted>
            <source src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>    
    </body>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("my_video_1").addEventListener("click", myfunc);
        // document.getElementById("my_video_1").onclick = myfunc; 

        function myfunc() {
            if (this.currentTime > 5) {
                location.href = "https://www.google.com";
            };
        }
    </script>
</html>
```